# Is it possible to modify the ArcObjects IProgressDialog2?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcobjects, c#

It turns out that the best way to run long tasks in ArcMap is to use the IProgressDialog2. The BackgroundWorker in combination with ArcObjects (STA Threads) is a mess.

However, it seems that the only implementation from ESRI is the IStepProgressor. In my case I do not need and do not want to show a progress bar. Moreover I do not need the cancel button.
Is there a way to remove both things? I want only the text and the circle as you can see in my screenshot [image: my progress dialog]

```
public static void ShowProgressDialog<T>(string message, Action<T> action, T arg)
    {

        ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.ITrackCancel trackCancel = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.CancelTrackerClass();

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IProgressDialogFactory progressDialogFactory = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ProgressDialogFactoryClass();

        // Set the properties of the Step Progressor
        System.Int32 int32_hWnd = ArcMap.Application.hWnd;
        ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.IStepProgressor stepProgressor = progressDialogFactory.Create(trackCancel, int32_hWnd);


        ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IProgressDialog2 progressDialog2 = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IProgressDialog2)stepProgressor; // Explict Cast

        progressDialog2.CancelEnabled = false;
        progressDialog2.Description = message;
        progressDialog2.Animation = ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.esriProgressAnimationTypes.esriProgressSpiral;

        action.Invoke(arg);

        trackCancel = null;
        progressDialog2.HideDialog();
        progressDialog2 = null;

    }
```

Comment: No, the progress dialog was not designed for such customizability. I guess since the dialog you are looking for is pretty plain, should be rather easy in WPF or WinForms to implement it yourself.

Comment: I suppose if you really wanted to you could hack the dialog with Windows API calls but meh...

Comment: Apart from the threading problem it would be even harder to implement a custom busy indicator that blocks the complete ArcMap GUI. You get it for free with the IProgressDialog2...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree about using the IProgressDialog2 with ArcGIS over other methods of showing progress. It always seems more reliable. I often use it for long running queries where I want to give the user the ability to cancel but don't know how long the query will take. In these cases I instantiate the dialog just like you do but before calling the action I simply hide the step progressor. The rest of the dialog will function and appear as normal. Add this just before you invoke the action:

```
stepProgressor.Hide();
progressDialog2.ShowDialog();
```

I don't know of a way to remove the cancel button.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. I think/hope the user can live with the cancel button. At least it is possible to disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `ProgressDialog` as [`IProgressor`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IProgressor_Interface/00420000017s000000/) to `.Hide` the progressor. Cast to `IProgressDialog` to set `CancelEnabled` to true.

Comment: Hiding the progressor is a duplicate of my answer Jason. Setting CancelEnabled to true does not remove the cancel button as the OP desired.